# How to derive derive De-Broglie's wavelength equation?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, momentum, mass-energy, wavelength

I was only yesterday learning about the De-Broglie equation $$\lambda = h/p, $$ I thought I understood it until I came across a question similar to this

[image]

Now I always knew that photons don't have any rest/invariant mass, but this question threw me off a bit, I think it was because of how my teacher derived it:

$$E=mc^2$$ $$E=hc/\lambda$$
$$mc^2 = hc/\lambda$$
$$p = h/\lambda$$
$$\lambda = h/p$$

Now he wrote $mc=p$ but that doesn't really apply to photons. So is this a wrong, or maybe a child friendly derivation?

(please make your answer simple, I don't know special relativity)

Answer (score 3):

The first two equations are inconsistent with each other.  The second applies to massless particles. And, indeed,  $mc=p$ doesn't apply to anything.  What your teacher has done, in essence, is an exercise in dimensional analysis.   A similar way to get to de Broglie is to ask "What combinations of $p$ and the fundamental constants of nature leads to a quantity whose dimension is a length?"

Answer (score 2):

You're over-complicating the issue. From special relativity, $E = pc$ for photons. From experimental observations, $E = hf$, from which we can obtain $E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$ by substituting $f = \frac{c}{\lambda}$. Then, equating these 2 equations gives $pc = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$, therefore $p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question correctly.

The basic problem is that there are two different things that are called mass: the rest mass and the kinetic mass.

The rest mass of a particle is the energy of the particle when it is not moving divided by $c^2$: $m_0 = E_0/c^2$. This is what you usually call the mass.

The term kinetic mass is a bit misleading. You define it as the whole energy of a moving particle divided by $c^2$: $m = E/c^2$, where $E = m_0 c^2 + E_{\mathrm{kin}}$. To avoid confusion in particle physics one does not use the term kinetic mass and only talks about the energy of a particle.

However in your question you are supposed to calculate the kinetic mass of the photon. This is simply given by the energy of the photon divided by $c^2$: $m = \frac{E}{c^2} = \frac{h f}{c^2} = \frac{h \frac{c}{\lambda}}{c^2} = \frac{h}{\lambda c}$ or $\lambda = \frac{h}{m c}$. So if you now insert this into the result of De-Broglie: $p = \frac{h}{\lambda} = m \cdot c$. So in fact since the velocity of the photon is $v = c$, you can write $p = m \cdot v$.

PS: The relation $p = m \cdot v$ holds for all particles in general. This is because the kinetic mass $m$ is defined such that this relation always holds.

Comment: The concept of kinetic mass is problematical, and not used in modern treatments.  Einstein warned against it.  Among other problems, it serves as a measure of inertia only in the direction of motion.   Transverse to the direction of motion, inertia is rest mass.